# How to change the style of a div that has as attribute a definite value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a problem. 
I have two divs:

```
<div class="cell" data-row-id="1" data-column-id="1"></div>     
<div class="cell" data-row-id="1" data-column-id="2"></div>
```

I have to modify the style of the div that has **data-row-id** = 1 and **data-column-id** = 2

Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried that's not working?

Comment: You might think about this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Comment: i have to modify the style using javascript not css!

Comment: @User19384 do you want achieve this goal with jquery or css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the data property as a CSS selector e.g:

```
.cell[data-column-id="2"] {
    background: tomato;
}
.cell[data-row-id="1"][data-column-id="2"] {
    background: green;
}
```

or using Javascript:

```
var el = document.querySelector('[data-column-id="2"]')
el.style.background = "tomato"
```

or using jQuery:

```
var el = $("[data-column-id='2']")
el.css("background", "tomato")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with data attributes selectors in CSS

```
[data-row-id="1"] {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the JavaScript Solution to your problem.

```js
document.querySelector('div[data-row-id="1"][data-column-id="2"]').style.color = 'green'
```

```html
<div class="cell" data-row-id="1" data-column-id="1">something 1</div>     
<div class="cell" data-row-id="1" data-column-id="2"> something 2</div>
```

Here is the CSS solution to your problem.

```css
div[data-row-id="1"][data-column-id="2"] {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell" data-row-id="1" data-column-id="1">something 1</div>     
<div class="cell" data-row-id="1" data-column-id="2"> something 2</div>
```

Here is the Jquery solution to your problem

```js
$('div[data-row-id="1"][data-column-id="2"]').css('color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cell" data-row-id="1" data-column-id="1">something 1</div>     
<div class="cell" data-row-id="1" data-column-id="2"> something 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target attributes using css attribute selector
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp

```
.cell[data-row-id="1"]{
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: i have to modify the style using javascript not css!

Comment: You should mention that in the question.